# Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automation, webdriver

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element ... is not clickable at point (1075, 323). Other element would receive the click: 
>     (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.130)

How to solve this error for selenium webdriver code..FOR CLICKING THE POST BUTTON using xpath the devloperr donot provide   id for that button 
CODE:

```java
WebElement element1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"SINPost\"]/button"));
element1.click();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using chrome it can happen sometimes, because chrome always tries to click at the middle of the element. What you can do is use JavaScriptExecutor interface of selenium. The code should look like this

```html
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) DriverManager.getWebDriver();
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Vector$1 cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor
 at demo.iNetwork_tab.main(iNetwork_tab.java:41)  after adding above command I got this error and also it not take .getwebdriver method

Comment: Hey, @vaidehi .getdriver is my custom method which returns me the webdriver. So in place of DriverManager.getWebDriver(); Please pass your webdriver.

Comment: this also not working I tried to create custom path but that thing also not working to lalocate  the button

Comment: the element will not locate  error continuously arrived, the button inspect only div id, class and button one click gave ..

Comment: I tried it by XPath, custom XPath, using javascript executor  CSS locator  by all ways it cant works

Comment: @vaidehi If nothing is working, Can you talk to your developers to provide you some Id or any other suitable locator. Because xpath can be of no use many times